# Avoid user changed data being overwritten?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app where you can enter some information about a customer. I have the problem that this information easily can be overwritten by other changes in the app.

I want:

1. A textarea showing the information
2. The message shown should update as changes are made to it in other places in the app
3. If the user has changed the message in the textarea, the message in the textarea should NOT be overwritten by server side changes or other changes in the app
4. When a save button is pressed, the model is updated

Simply doing this:

```
<textarea ng-model="customer.info"></textarea>
<button ng-click="save(customer)">Save</button>
```

won't work, because if something is changed to the customer object on the server, the information field will be reset and the user's changes will be overwritten.

Comment: So what you want is basically `<textarea readonly></textarea>`?

Comment: Try angular.copy(src) to save a copy of the object on the scope; then when ready use angular.copy(src, dst) to persist the changes on the original object.

Answer (score 0):

***Update:***
In response to your comment/updated question: I'd simply track the state of the textarea using a couple of event listeners, that check if the user changed the value. If so: the textarea is no longer kept in sync with the server data.
I also check if the textarea has focus, if that is the case, the value should not be updated, because the user might be editing its contents.

Lastly, I've attached a blur event handler, that checks the value again, in case the user *"undoes"* changes. If a user adds a char by accident, and removes it later on, the textarea's value might be the same as the last known value that came from the server, in which case, the textarea's value should be kept in-sync again.

I've set up a simple fiddle that uses an interval to do all this. Replace the interval-related code with your worker, ajax callback or whatever it is you're using. If it's a worker, unsetting the interval should be replaced with unbinding the `onmessage` handlers with a handler function that syncs the textarea or doesn't sync the textarea. Alternatively use a single function that checks the `changed` flag whenever it wants to change the textarea's value. Plain and simple.
***[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fjA43/)***
And here's the code (the fiddle version contains some actual comments that explain various bits and pieces):

```
(function (txt)
{
    var initialValue = txt.value,
        changed = false,
        id,
        callback = function()
        {
            if (changed === false)
                initialValue = (txt.value += ' Server-sync');
            else
            {
                clearInterval(id);
                id = null;
            }
        };
    txt.addEventListener('change', function()
    {
        if (this.value !== initialValue)
            changed = true;
    }, false);
    txt.addEventListener('focus', function()
    {
        changed = true;
    }, false);
    txt.addEventListener('blur', function()
    {
        if (this.value !== initialValue)
            changed = true;
        else
        {
            changed = false;
            id = setInterval(callback, 5000);
        }
    }, false);
    id = setInterval(callback,5000);
}(document.querySelector('#foo')));
```

---

*Initial answer*

Like I said in my comment:

```
<textarea ng-model="customer.info" id='foo' readonly></textarea>
```

prevents the value of the textare from being altered by the user, but you can still set/change its value in your JS code:

```
var changeTxt = (function(txt)
{
    return function(addVal)
    {
        txt.value += addVal;
    };
}(document.querySelector('#foo')));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WdnZn/)

To keep the value of the textArea in sync, you could perform an AJAX call prior to making any changes to the value client side, or create a worker *"thread"* that polls the server for changes that have been made since the value was last fetched.

Seeing as you're using angular.js, I must admit that I don't have any experience with how angular can be best used to solve your issue, but a quick google search lead me to [3-way data binding](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/wKhWRNnWuX/4-three-way-data-binding-with-a-real-time-server), which does look rather promising.

Comment: @MarkusJohansson: Then point 3 in your question is rather unclear... what exactly is it that you mean by _"user changed the message in the text area, the message in the textarea should NOT change"_?

Comment: @MarkusJohansson: If by that you mean: once the user changes the message, it should not be kept in sync with the server data, then you could simply use a change event, to stop polling the server for updates, or kill the worker thread, or whatever

Comment: Yes that was a bit unclear. I have updated the question. The main point is that I don't want the content to be overwritten just because there comes a change to the customer model from the server. I don't want to stop retrieving other unrelated changes just because the user is editing.

Comment: @MarkusJohansson: Edited my answer + added fiddle. The textarea in the fiddle is updated every 5 seconds, unless it has focus, or the value was altered. If you undo all changes, the value is auto-synced again